# Is it possible to call a method defined inside a static class of another activity in the main activity (Android)?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, locale, static-classes

So I have a method `loadLocale()` which I want to use in the MainActivity to set user preferred language stored in shared preferences. The SettingsActivity code looks like below :

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AppPreferenceFragment appPreferenceFragment=(AppPreferenceFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PreferenceFragment");
        if(appPreferenceFragment==null)
            appPreferenceFragment = new AppPreferenceFragment();

        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, appPreferenceFragment, "PreferenceFragment")
                .commit();

    }


    public static class AppPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener
    {
        
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            loadLocale();
            //Some other code
            Preference pref_al = findPreference("select_app_language");
            pref_al.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            //SOME CODE

            else if (preference.getKey().compareTo("select_pref_language")==0){
                setupSelectLanguageDialog();
            }
            return false;
        }



        public void setupAppLanguageDialog()
        {
            AlertDialog langChangeDialog;
            CharSequence[] changeLangList = {"English", "हिन्दी"};
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            mBuilder.setTitle("Choose language");
            mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(changeLangList, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (i==0)
                    {
                        setLocale("en");
                        getActivity().recreate();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        setLocale("hi");
                        getActivity().recreate();
                    }
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            langChangeDialog =mBuilder.create();
            langChangeDialog.show();

        }

        public void setLocale(String lang) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getResources().updateConfiguration(config ,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            DataRepository.setAppLanguage(lang);
            Log.v("locale",DataRepository.getUserData("app_lang"));
        }

        //load langauge saved in shared prefrences
        public void loadLocale()
        {
            String app_lang= DataRepository.getAppLanguage();

            if(InputValidator.isNullorEmpty(app_lang) || app_lang.equals(Constants.NO_DATA)){
                Log.v("Locale","Empty");
                return;
            }

            setLocale(app_lang);
            Log.v("loaded Locale",app_lang);
        }
```

I want to call `loadLocale()` method in my mainActivity so that when the application starts , the preferred language is selected by default. My mainActivity looks like :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Some declarations
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //I want to set my app language here by calling loadLocale()
    //loadLocale();

//other code

}
```

I can re-write both the functions again the MainActivity to do so. Is there a better way out?

NOTE : `DataRepository.getAppLanguage()` and `DataRepository.setAppLanguage()` are methods to store and get app language via SharedPreferences

Comment: Why not just move loadLocale to a different static class and then use that in both SettingsActivity and MainActivity. I am not sure whether this is the right way to do something like this, which is why I am leaving a comment

Comment: You should be architecting your app so that there is no _business logic_ in the Activity classes. Best to move the `loadLocale()` functionality to a different class then call that class method from your target Activity

Comment: @najm Thank you for the suggestions, I am a beginner and still learning about the guidelines used for android dev. So, even if I declare another static class, and write my method there, how can I call it in my MainActivity ? I tried to something like `public static LanguageUtils.LocaleUtils localeUtils; localeUtils.loadLocale();` and it gives me a null Pointer exception. I guess it is not the right way to code business logic. Can you please detail/ suggest a pointer on writing such codes/queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't just make a Class with only static functions, passing Parameters if needed and add return type if needed. Then you can call it from anywhere. Example:

```
class Helper {
    public static void loadLocale(Context context)
    {
        String app_lang= DataRepository.getAppLanguage();

        if(InputValidator.isNullorEmpty(app_lang) || app_lang.equals(Constants.NO_DATA)){
            Log.v("Locale","Empty");
            return;
        }

        setLocale(app_lang, context);
        Log.v("loaded Locale",app_lang);
    }

    public static void setLocale(String lang, Context context) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config ,context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        DataRepository.setAppLanguage(lang);
        Log.v("locale",DataRepository.getUserData("app_lang"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But if you notice, `loadLocale()` called `setLocale()` which further calls `getResources().updateConfiguration(config ,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());` which requires a static class. I tried using `context.getResources` (passing the context whenever function is called) but it doesn't work. Any alternatives/suggestions?

Comment: You can put the setLocale function into Helper class , Just Override the code you can try this , it should work

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, it turned out I wasn't passing the context right, I had to pass `getActivity().getBaseContext()`whereas I was passing `getActivity()` only , that made all the difference. Also , I made the member functions static in the helper class.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, you should be able to achieve your target by calling `new SettingsActivity.AppPreferenceFragment().loadLocale();`, so your `MainActivity` will look like the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Some declarations
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //I want to set my app language here by calling loadLocale()
        AppPreferenceFragment appPreferenceFragment=(AppPreferenceFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("PreferenceFragment_MainActivity");
        if(appPreferenceFragment==null)
            appPreferenceFragment = new AppPreferenceFragment();

        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            // have a hidden framelayout as flPrefContent in the XML file attached with this activity
            .replace(R.id.flPrefContent, appPreferenceFragment, "PreferenceFragment_MainActivity")
            .commit();
        appPreferenceFragment.loadLocale();

        //other code

    }
}
```

But as @najm has suggested in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976313/is-it-possible-to-call-a-method-defined-inside-a-static-class-of-another-activit#comment111366274_62976313), you should extract such logics in probably a singleton class and use methods as `loadLocale()`, `setLocale()` etc. of that class from anywhere in your app like in `MainActivity`, `SettingsActivity` and so on.

Comment: I tried this, and I am getting this exception : 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment AppPreferenceFragment{ae21c79} not attached to Activity .

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can suggest an outline of how to frame this business logic ,if you had to do so.

Comment: @segfault404 try the updated code & it is exactly why this structure is not OK! Observing your code, I can suggest 2 things to fix this part of the structure - 1. move your `setLocale()` & `loadLocale()` methods inside your `DataRepository` class & 2. use `DataRepository` class as singleton, not for static access.